# Creating an assembly from Xamarin (or Module), then importing it into Swift?

Tags: swift, xamarin.ios, xamarin

That would be the million dollar question!  Is it possible to create an assembly in Xamarin (C#) for IOS, then import that into a Swift project?

I am getting really into Swift and I know there are some major things that I am still missing such as the ease of calling a web service, etc...  So what I want to do is create a web service call in a Xamarin Assembly (or module) and use the Imports into Swift to import and reference my assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no. It's designed to consume iOS libraries and you can create bindings to use them.......but not the other way around.

Either use Swift or Xamarin. If Xamarin you could create libraries in Swift and consume in Xamarin (but why would you if it wasn't a 3rd party library).....but you can't create libraries in Xamarin to consume in Swift.

If connecting to a web service is your only hurdle with Swift then that's probably  not a good single reason to switch to Xamarin.